# OpenCV CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES when running code that worked before

Tags: python, windows, opencv

I am running OpenCV to stitch some images together and before today was working fine, but after trying to run similar code today I am getting error messages.
Code is:

```
import cv2
import os

images =[]
path = "Folder"
for image in os.listdir(path):
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,image))
    images.append(img)
print("There are {} images".format(len(images)))
print("Images are read")
print("Creating stitcher")
stitcher = cv2.Stitcher.create(mode=1)
print("Stitcher is running")
(status, stitched) = stitcher.stitch(images)
cv2.imwrite("File.png", stitched)
```

And the errors I am getting are:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0)
> D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\ocl.cpp:5954:
> error: (-220:Unknown error code -220) OpenCL error CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES
> (-5) during call: clEnqueueReadBuffer(q, handle=000001C39C840AE0,
> CL_TRUE, 0, sz=1583382528, data=000001C4E6132080, 0, 0, 0) in function
> 'cv::ocl::OpenCLAllocator::map' OpenCV(4.6.0) Error: Unknown error
> code -220 (OpenCL error CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE (-36) during call:
> clEnqueueMapBuffer(handle=000001C3FB376060, sz=3341583) =>
> 0000000000000000) in cv::ocl::OpenCLAllocator::deallocate_, file
> D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\ocl.cpp, line
> 5761

I have tried to search up some results but I couldn't find a similar scenario

I have had the same code but with a different path running and it has been reading a lot more images and it does not throw any errors (147MB folder vs a 70MB folder which throws the error), am I missing a way to purge my memory or something?

Comment: you could convert your image to a type that takes up less memory. Extreme example that could work is `img=img.astype(numpy.byte)` if all values in your image can be in 0-255 range.

Comment: [`cv.ocl.setUseOpenCL(False)`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/d83/group__core__opencl.html#gab747fa4efd88d3188f4ebcbc8a639c1e) should hopefully work around the issue -- figure out why it's out of memory. is something else using your gpu memory? did you update OpenCV since you last used it? have you tried turning your computer off and on again? is your web browser open, with lots of tabs?

Comment: I have no idea what is using my memory, Task Manager is saying hardly any of it is being used with the IDE and Python not being close to the top anyway. Computer and graphics drivers have been restarted a couple of times. Same version of OpenCV both times. I am doing a test run using jpegs instead of PNGs to see how that goes